# Does over-completing challenges earn extra XP in Mario Golf GBC?

Tags: mario-golf-gbc

When doing side quests in Mario Golf for Game Boy Color, you are often given challenges to complete a task a certain number of times with a set number of attempts. You can keep playing after completing the objective, meaning some challenges can be beaten it by clearing 7 out of 10 shots or 10 out of 10 shots.

Does over-completing these challenges earn extra experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. At least for certain challenges, over-completing them earns extra XP if you complete them "perfectly". This applies to clearing every shot on "Get within range X times" challenges and getting in the hole on single shot accuracy challenges. I tested a few scenarios using save states.

Can give Extra XP:

- Malon Club's Putting Contest: 20xp for getting 7, 8, or 9 shots out of 10. 25xp for getting all 10 shots.
- Tiny-Tot's Golf Grounds: 50xp when I missed 1 or 2 shots and 62xp when every shot was cleared. (There was also different dialogue)
- Malon Club's Approach Lesson (girl on right side): 20xp when my shot was in range of the pin. 25xp when my shot landed in the hole via chip-in.

I couldn't find a way to earn extra XP on scenarios that didn't match this criteria, typically because the conditions to "overcomplete" them were less clear. Ones where I am unsure if you can earn XP include:

- Golf Guru's Pitch & Putt: Complete 9 holes in one shot and 1 putt. Maybe would give extra XP for a hole in one on each hole?
- Raven Woods Course: Completed by getting a pin shot to knock a crow off.